# How can I create a select list with all languages?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I need to have a field on a form, where the user can choose from the set of world languages for an event.

It's going to be an Autocomplete term widget (tagging) field.

How can I reuse the inbuilt language list in Drupal for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is the [_locale_get_predefined_list](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!iso.inc/function/_locale_get_predefined_list/7) which return you an array.
so you need to do the field yourself.

you also could try [language_field](http://drupal.org/project/languagefield), you should be able to use that directly in your form.